# MongoDB Aggregation: grouping data within date groups

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have many documents in a MongoDB database which look like the following four documents (note the first 3 are Feb 2017 and the last one is March 2017):

```
{"_id": 0,
 "date": ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z),
 "item": "Basketball",
 "category": "Sports"}

{"_id": 1,
 "date": ISODate("2017-02-13T00:00:00Z),
 "item": "Football",
 "category": "Sports"}

{"_id": 2,
 "date": ISODate("2017-02-22T00:00:00Z),
 "item": "Massage",
 "category": "Leisure"}

{"_id": 3,
 "date": ISODate("2017-03-05T00:00:00Z),
 "item": "Golf club",
 "category": "Sports"}
```

I'm trying to group the items by MONTH/YEAR and within that, group the items by CATEGORY. So the aggregation pipeline should return something that looks like this for the four docs above:

```
{"_id": {
   "month": 2,
   "year": 2017
   },
 "data": [
   {"category": "Sports",
    "items": ["Basketball", "Football"]
   },
   {"category": "Leisure",
    "items": ["Massage"]
   }
 ]
},
{"_id": {
   "month": 3,
   "year": 2017
   },
 "data": [
   {"category": "Sports",
    "items": ["Golf Club"]
   }
 ]
}
```

I also want the returned cursor to be in order with year as the primary sort and month as the secondary sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Here's the answer using the pymongo api:

```
from bson.son import SON

cursor = db.collection.aggregate([
  {'$group': {
    '_id': {'month': {'$month': '$date'},
            'year': {'$year': '$date'},
            '$category': '$category'},
    'items': {'$push': '$item'}
  }},
  {'$group': {
    '_id': {'month': '_id.month',
            'year': '_id.year'}
    'data': {
      '$push': {
        'category': '$_id.category',
        'items': '$items'
      }
    }
  }},
  {'$sort': SON([('_id.year', 1), ('_id.month', 1)])}
])
my_data = list(cursor)
```